# How to iterate through folders and subfolders to delete n number of files randomly?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I have 4 folders (named W1, W3, W5, W7) and each one of those folders has approximately 30 subfolders (named M1 - M30). Each subfolder contains 24 .tif files (named Image_XX.tif).

I need to randomly "sample" each subfolder, more specifically, I need to get rid of 14 .tif files while keeping 10 .tif files in each subfolder.

I figure that deleting 14 files at random is easier than choosing 10 files at random and copying them to new subfolders within folders.

I thought that writing a bash script to do so would be the way, but I'm fairly new to programming and I'm stuck.

Below is one of the several scripts I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /Users/Fer/Subsets/W1/; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        cd "$dir"
        gshuf -zn14 -e *.tif | xargs -0 rm
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

It runs for a second, but nothing seems to happen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `for dir in /Users/Fer/Subsets/W[1357]/*; do ...`

Comment: You need to navigate to each subfolder _separately_ or do you want to remove 14 files from all of them together? `has approximately 30 ` `I need to get rid of 14 .tif files while keeping 10 .tif files` So you want to remove 14 or keep 10?

Comment: Note that there is no need to `cd`, simply `gshuf -zn14 -e "$dir"/*.tif | xargs -0 rm`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I need to navigate to each subfolder separately and remove 14 files from each subfolder. Each subfolder currently has 24 files, I want to keep 10 only.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thank you, the line you suggested together with what KamilCuk suggested below did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used some of the suggestions above and the code below worked:

```
for dir in /Users/Fer/Subsets/W*/M*; do
    gshuf -zn14 -e "$dir"/*.tif | xargs -0 rm
done
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For every subdirectory.

   1. Find all files.
   2. Choose a random number of files from the list.
   3. Delete.

I think something along:

```
for dir in /Users/Fer/Subsets/W*/M*/; do
    printf "%s\n" "$dir"/*.tif |
    shuf -z -n 14 |
    xargs -0 -t echo rm -v
done
```